# How to creat table result in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Have 4 tables

Table User

```
id  |  user
-----------
55   |  Jhon    
56   |  Krish   
57   |  Boss
```

Table Payout

```
id  |  Payout_Date
------------------
1   |  31.10.2015
2   |  24.10.2015
3   |  17.10.2015
```

Table Earning

```
Userid  |  Date       |  Earning
------------------------------------
55      |  31.10.2015 |  5$
56      |  31.10.2015 |  1$
57      |  31.10.2015 |  3$
55      |  30.10.2015 |  5$
56      |  30.10.2015 |  12$
57      |  30.10.2015 |  0$
55      |  29.10.2015 |  5$
56      |  29.10.2015 |  4$
```

When i add a new Payout date (Payout_Date)

I Want who earn >10$ in their Last payment date between new payout out date , If not pay before that user, their Last Payment_Date is No(get all earning)

then add that results to table "Payment". with new Payout_Date to Payment_Date, Their Last Payment_Date is From_Date.

Table Payment

```
 id | Userid   |  From_Date  |  Payment_Date |  Earning  |  Status
------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |  55      |  24.10.2015 |  31.10.2015   |  12$      |  0
  2 |  56      |  24.10.2015 |  31.10.2015   |  17$      |  0
```

How to write that on Codeignaiter Controller and Model

Sorry for my English grammar mistake.

Comment: I didn't get you. what you expecting ?

Comment: Please check now that quations

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking about CodeIgniter, think about the database query you want to run. You want all the data from two tables when two condition are met. So you will want to join the tables together and show the results when earning is over $10 and (I'm guessing) when the From_Date is before or equal to the latest Payment_Date, but after the previous Payment_Date.

In CodeIgniter, they give you a more forgiving way to write your queries, but the mechanics are still the same.

So you could probably write a single, gnarly query that does this all at once, but it would be far easier to split it into a couple of queries:

1. query for the most recent payment date before today.
2. query for the payment date before that.
3. query for the user earnings between those two dates.

I'll show you my best guess at what you want in Query 3 and then point you to [the CI Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html). I am assuming you are doing this query in a class that extends CI_Model. I've tried to use the simplest-to-read syntax. Also, I'm assuming you will remove the `$` from the values in the Earning column and just use a number. (I haven't tested this code, but it should get you close.)

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select($currentPaymentDateFoundInQuery1'. AS Payment_Date');  // add a column with Payment_Date
$this->db->from('User');
$this->db->join('Earning', 'Earning.Userid=User.id');
$this->db->where('Earning >', 10);
$this->db->where('Date >', $previousPaymentDateFromQuery2);
$this->db->where('Date <=', $currentPaymentDateFoundInQuery1);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it should get you started. The second select statement just creates an extra column in the results with the current payment date.